# Increase Latitude and longitude by given Distance (meter) Using JAVA

Tags: java, groovy

I am getting Latitude and Longitude from the inputs and need to increase the Latitude and Longitude by 50 Meters.

The solution we need to achieve, given Latitude and Longitude we are proving all the 50 Meters places as well. So Let me know how to get New Latitude and Longitude by increasing 50 Meters.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "increasing 50 meter"? Do you want to move? Which direction do you want to move in? (North, south, east, west, a particular number of degrees from north, etc?)

Comment: Hello. You should show your code so we can know what you're trying to do. The question will be eventually downvoted and / or closed if you do not do that.

Comment: I am new this geolocation program. My Idea is: Given Latitude and Longitude need to search 50 meters surrounding area. How to do in java?